# Loops using levelsof producing invalid name error

Tags: stata

My data in Stata has the variables `category`, `qtr`, `output`. It is producing the error 'var' invalid name r(198);

I am not quite sure what I am doing wrong. If someone could also check if I am doing the `graph export` right, I'd really appreciate it.

This is what my Stata results window looks like

```
. levelsof category, local(levels)
`"Accommodation"' `"Accommodation and food services"' `"Administrative and support services"' `"Administrative and waste manageme
> nt services"' `"Agriculture, forestry, fishing, and hunting"' `"Air transportation"' `"All industries"' `"Ambulatory health car
> e services"' `"Amusements, gambling, and recreation industries"' `"Apparel and leather and allied products"' `"Arts, entertainm
> ent, and recreation"' `"Arts, entertainment, recreation, accommodation, and food services"' `"Broadcasting and telecommunicatio
> ns"' `"Chemical products"' `"Computer and electronic products"' `"Computer systems design and related services"' `"Construction
> "' `"Data processing, internet publishing, and other information services"' `"Durable goods"' `"Educational services"' `"Educat
> ional services, health care, and social assistance"' `"Electrical equipment, appliances, and components"' `"Fabricated metal pr
> oducts"' `"Farms"' `"Federal"' `"Federal General government"' `"Federal Government enterprises"' `"Federal Reserve banks, credi
> t intermediation, and related activities"' `"Finance and insurance"' `"Finance, insurance, real estate, rental, and leasing"' `
> "Food and beverage and tobacco products"' `"Food and beverage stores"' `"Food services and drinking places"' `"Forestry, fishin
> g, and related activities"' `"Funds, trusts, and other financial vehicles"' `"Furniture and related products"' `"General mercha
> ndise stores"' `"Government"' `"Health care and social assistance"' `"Hospitals"' `"Housing"' `"Information"' `"Insurance carri
> ers and related activities"' `"Legal services"' `"Machinery"' `"Management of companies and enterprises"' `"Manufacturing"' `"M
> ining"' `"Mining, except oil and gas"' `"Miscellaneous manufacturing"' `"Miscellaneous professional, scientific, and technical 
> services"' `"Motion picture and sound recording industries"' `"Motor vehicle and parts dealers"' `"Motor vehicles, bodies and t
> railers, and parts"' `"National defense"' `"Nondefense"' `"Nondurable goods"' `"Nonmetallic mineral products"' `"Not allocated 
> by industry1"' `"Nursing and residential care facilities"' `"Oil and gas extraction"' `"Other real estate"' `"Other retail"' `"
> Other services, except government"' `"Other transportation and support activities"' `"Other transportation equipment"' `"Paper 
> products"' `"Performing arts, spectator sports, museums, and related activities"' `"Petroleum and coal products"' `"Pipeline tr
> ansportation"' `"Plastics and rubber products"' `"Primary metals"' `"Printing and related support activities"' `"Private goods-
> producing industries2"' `"Private industries"' `"Private services-producing industries3"' `"Professional and business services"
> ' `"Professional, scientific, and technical services"' `"Publishing industries, except internet (includes software)"' `"Rail tr
> ansportation"' `"Real estate"' `"Real estate and rental and leasing"' `"Rental and leasing services and lessors of intangible a
> ssets"' `"Retail trade"' `"Securities, commodity contracts, and investments"' `"Social assistance"' `"State and local"' `"State
> /Local General government"' `"State/Local Government enterprises"' `"Support activities for mining"' `"Textile mills and textil
> e product mills"' `"Transit and ground passenger transportation"' `"Transportation and warehousing"' `"Truck transportation"' `
> "Utilities"' `"Warehousing and storage"' `"Waste management and remediation services"' `"Water transportation"' `"Wholesale tra
> de"' `"Wood products"'

. foreach l of local levels {
  2.         line output qtr if category == `l'
  3.         graph save gph_`l' "gph_`l'.gph", replace
  4.         graph export "gph_`l'.png", replace
  5. }
Accommodation not found
r(111);
```

I want a separate graph for each unique value in `category`. Initially, I tried using the `by()` option but since I have 100 different unique levels it results in very small graphs.

I also attempted to `reshape wide` but then I get a lot of other issues (invalid variable name errors, reshape error even though data has no duplicates - I checked).

Here is a picture for a clearer idea; it has same thing as in the code snippet:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YF5xy.png)

Comment: Your urgency is no doubt genuine but private. It is not a criterion here.

Comment: For more on claims of urgency, and why they don't help or are deprecated, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest

Comment: Cross-posted at https://www.reddit.com/r/stata/comments/137yfme/urgent_loops_using_levels_invalid_name_error/

Answer (score 0):

There is no data example here to test, but I can guess at three errors.

Problem 1. `category` is manifestly a string variable, so its distinct values need to be included within double quotes in your call to `line`. When you don't specify double quotes to indicate a literal string, Stata tries to identify what you typed as the *name* of a variable (or scalar), but that fails at the first hurdle, as you have no variable or scalar called `Accommodation`, as the error message flags.

```
foreach l of local levels {
    line output qtr if category == "`l'"
    graph save gph_`l' "gph_`l'.gph", replace
    graph export "gph_`l'.png", replace
}
```

Problems 2 and 3. The current graph won't have a name unless you assign one and in any case if you gave a name you'd need to watch out for spaces within your string values. It is simpler just to `save` the current graph directly to a file.

```
foreach l of local levels {
    line output qtr if category == "`l'"
    graph save "gph_`l'.gph", replace
    graph export "gph_`l'.png", replace
}
```

Note that as explained in https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/try-all-values-with-foreach/ it can be a lot easier to loop over numeric levels 1 up than to handle long and possibly complicated strings. So, if the approach above fails, consider

```
egen cat = group(category), label 
su cat, meanonly 
local max = r(max) 

forval j = 1/`max' { 
    line output qtr if cat == `j' 
    graph save "gph_`j'.gph", replace
    graph export "gph_`j'.png", replace
}
```

However, getting this to work is only the first step. Nothing on any of your graphs indicates which category is being shown. So you should specifiy that in some title, say

```
egen cat = group(category), label 
su cat, meanonly 
local max = r(max) 

forval j = 1/`max' { 
    local which : label (cat) `j' 
    line output qtr if cat == `j', subtitle("`which'") 
    graph save "gph_`j'.gph", replace
    graph export "gph_`j'.png", replace
}
```

Detail: I try to avoid the lower case letter `l` as a local macro name, as I then struggle to be clear that I haven't typed the numeral `1` instead.

Detail: I doubt that `reshape wide` would have helped here at all.

Detail: I think that the first error message reported in the question refers to an earlier version of your code.